# Высота header равная высоте окна

Tags: javascript, css

Нужно сделать header на странице по высоте равный окну.

Я знаю, что высоту можно получить с помощью `document.documentElement.clientHeight`, но так как я новичок я просто не понимаю, как это сделать.

Comment: height: 100vh ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header {
   height: 100vh; 
}
```

https://tipue.com/blog/css3-vw-vh/

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо растянуть `header` При каком-то действии через именно `js`, как в вопросе, то можно так:

```
<style>
    header{
        background-color: #003eff;
        height: 100px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<header>Пурум Пум Пум</header>
<script language="JavaScript">
    var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight; // Получаем высоту окна
    document.body.addEventListener('click', function () { // Отслеживаем нажатие на header(Можно другие триггеры использовать)
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('header'); // Получаем header
        head[0].style.height = height; // Меняем высоту.
    })
</script>
```